# FLUTTER app unable to display network images in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, whatsapp, networkimageview

I have build a whatsapp clone ui it displays images well in debug mode but when i built apk it do not show any image please help anyone

**My Apps Menifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.milan.whatsapp.whatsapp_clone">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

## buildGradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.milan.whatsapp.whatsapp_clone"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

## code of activity--

```
 leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
          info[index]['profilePic'].toString(),
            ),
          ),
```

here info has the Jsonfile where all the data is present like the image links

## output in Debug Mode is Shown below

[Screen in debugmode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWiLC.jpg)

## output after building the release apk

[Screen in release mode without images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdYPw.jpg)

I just added permissons in the andorid manifest file
which is uploaded above

Comment: I'm not really sure but did u uncomment your >>assets: - assets/ in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: No I did not do that as I have not used any assets in my project
The images are displayed from
Web